# How windows loader deal with TLS (Thread Local Storage)

Tags: multithreading

I am writing a packer but it did not work with programs which use **TLS (Thread Local Storage )**. So how windows loader deal with it ?

Comment: The loader is not involved with TLS.  It, at best, helps a program to call TlsAlloc() correctly by calling DllMain() with the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notification.  The usual downfall when programmers write their own loader, very hard to get right.

Comment: it is really downfall ... but there is some packer did , like UPX . so can you guide me to the general idea ?